# Use Angular2 Change detection mechanism

Tags: angular

Can I know if any of my object's descendants properties are been changed? 
Can I subscribe to some event that will notice me?

Answer (score 0):

If they are `@Input() myProp` then you can implement `ngOnChanges(changes)` and fire events using an `@Output()` but you need to prepare your descandants to do that.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-cmp'
}) {
export class Child {
  @Input() fooInput:string;
  @Input() barInput:number;
  @Output() changes:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    this.changes.emit(changes);
  }
}
```

```
<child-cmp (changes)="childChangesHandler($event)">
```

Events emitted by `@Output()`s don't bubble, therefore you get only notifications of direct children. If you need this for more levels use a shared service instead.

Comment: Your answer is good for components but my question was on object/model.
If I have a complex model e.g. School->rooms->chairs 
and my user is changing the name of a specific chair.
Can I know that my School model has been changed?
I guess that I will have to check it every ngOnChanges() check?

Comment: Then I don't see how your question is related to Angular2. Can you please add some code that shows what you actually try to accomplish? In classes you can add a `Rx.Subject` (because `EventEmitter` is discouraged to be used for anything except `@Outputs()`. Then implement your properties as getter/setter and fire an event in `set`

Comment: I guess my problem is not specific for Angular2 but I hoped that maybe Angular2 will have a solution for it.

Comment: Angular does nothing with plain classes and their instances.